# Magento CSS files not loading with https url

Tags: magento2, css, ssl, https

I have installed SSL certificate and now when I access the website [link to secure website](https://www.deals4u.co.il)  CSS files are not loading. 
CSS files are loading in not secured url . Also url links inside the website returning 404:

Please help me solve this issue.
I tried to deploy but that did not help.

Comment: Did you change the base URLs in Magento Admin to https as well? What does your configuration look like?

Comment: tried to change admin to secure but than got thrown out so switched back admin to unsecure. frontend is secure but css errors and links not working.

Comment: You need to update all URLs to https and then clear the cache.

Comment: Also: If you want to serve the whole shop via HTTPS also set: "Use Secure URLs on Storefront" to Yes.

Comment: they need to update automatically. what do you mean?

Comment: i did Use Secure URLs on Storefront. that did not help

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your configuration looks like this:

Stores > Configuration > General > Web:

Base URLs:

- Base URL: https://www.yourdomain.com/
- Base Link URL: [X] Use system
  value (will be the same as base URL)

Base URLs (Secure):

- Secure Base URL: https://www.yourdomain.com/
- Secure Base Link URL: {{secure_base_url}}
- Use Secure URLs on Storefront: Yes
- Use Secure URLs in Admin: Yes
- Enable HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS): Yes
- Upgrade Insecure Requests: Yes

**After** changing the URLs, clear the cache! You might as well need to a new deployment and/or run
`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and clear the cache again.

Comment: Enable HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS): Yes
Upgrade Insecure Requests: Yes.                                                                        are not showing up on web section

Comment: maybe i have premissions issue?

Comment: You need to save the secure base url first and then reload the page. Then the 2 options will show up.

Comment: they dont show up..

Comment: Which version of Magento 2.x is this? Actually they should show up. However, these 2 are security features which should be enabled when you run your shop via https but they have nothing to do with the fact that CSS is loaded via https in the frontend.

Comment: @YossiBondasd you need to have options web/secure/use_in_frontend and web/secure/use_in_adminhtml to 1